# dojo: how to i know all the extension points of a widget

Tags: dojo

Say for example that i have a grid (dojox.grid.DataGrid). I want to know all the extension points available on that grid.
When checked with the dojo api doc in events section of the grid i cant find the extension points, (say for example extension point onBeforeRow is not listed in that event section).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much every public method is an extension point, in that you can dojo.connect to it.  The "on" pattern indicates an event pattern, and there's no formal declaration beyond the naming pattern AFAIK.

Comment: true, the on pattern is an extension point. But, i like to see or log all possible extension points. Assume mygird is a grid widget. In firebug console if i type mygird.on, all the events are listed but onBeforeRow is not listed. But onBeforeRow is not listed in events of the grid. But onBeforeRow is a key extension point for custom rows. This applies for all widgets.

Comment: can somebody help me with this